# How to get value of global variables from OpenCL kernel to host C++ program?

Tags: cuda, opencl

In CUDA driver API, there is a function called `cuModuleGetGlobal` which allows you to get the value of a global variable in a CUDA module (an object of already built CUDA program) by its name. I'm wondering if OpenCL has the same function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, OpenCL 1.2 does not offer a method to read back the value of a global variable.

However, this is not a huge restriction.  In OpenCL, program scope variables (i.e. global variables) must be defined in the `__constant` address space and must be initialized using a compile-time constant.  In consequence, kernels can never change the value of global variables.  So one can easily track the value of the global variable in the host code.

Comment: you don't get to decide how huge this restriction is..

Comment: @DávidTóth How does your comment add anything to the answer? I provided an explanation why this is not a huge restriction. If the explanation is wrong or does no longer hold (keep in mind that this question is over 10 years old), please elaborate on why that is the case.

Comment: it is a matter of personal opinion whether something is a huge restriction or not.

Comment: So what? In my opinion this is not a huge restriction. You seem to disagree, which is fine by me. But merely stating your opinion without any justification still doesn't add anything substantial to the discussion.

Comment: Yes! I agree! Stating your opinion is not contributing in a meaningful way.